# Generate a pandas dataframe from collections.OrderedDict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, collections, ordereddictionary

I have to open this xml file from this [website](https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/download/8s6p-h233/text%2Fxml) and make a dataframe.

I tried to pas a xml to dict and then pass to dataframe

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict
from io import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
import pandas as pd


file = urlopen('https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/download/8s6p-h233/text%2Fxml')
data_bytes = file.read()
orderDictListData = xmltodict.parse(data_bytes)
orderDictListData 
df = pd.DataFrame(orderDictListData)
```

I need a dataframe since key "id" until "codiINEmunicipi" like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply using [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html):

```
url = 'https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/download/8s6p-h233/text%2Fxml'
df = pd.read_xml(url)
```

output:

```
     id                                                   nom                                                                        carrec tractament                 resp  iddep                                                                     dep  idpare codidep          nif   ordre datamodificacio datacreacio  centres  sinonims
0   535                                 012 Atenció Ciutadana                                                                          None       None                 None   3392  Departament de la Vicepresidència i de Polítiques Digitals i Territori    6564     PTO         None  912000      02/06/2021  19/06/1997      NaN       NaN
1  3383                                      061 Salut Respon                                                                          None       None                 None   2803                                                    Departament de Salut    7021     SLT         None    1000      23/02/2021  19/06/1997      NaN       NaN
2  5500  ACCIÓ - Agència per a la Competitivitat de l'Empresa  consellera delegada de l'Agència per a la Competitivitat de l'Empresa, ACCIÓ       Sra.     Natàlia Mas Guix  19775                                         Departament d'Empresa i Treball   19035     EMO  S-0800476-D  323699      28/02/2022  19/06/1997      NaN       NaN
3  5504                                        ACCIÓ a Girona                                                      delegat d'ACCIÓ a Girona        Sr.        Ferran Rodero  19775                                         Departament d'Empresa i Treball    5500     EMO         None   10500      25/01/2016  19/06/1997      NaN       NaN
4  5505                                        ACCIÓ a Lleida                                                     delegada d'ACCIÓ a Lleida       Sra.  Clara Porta Sànchez  19775                                         Departament d'Empresa i Treball    5500     EMO         None   11500      25/01/2016  19/06/1997      NaN       NaN
...
```